# Apply a list of functions to a value in Ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

How would I best create this function in [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/)?

```
function get_list (value) {
  return [
    first_transform(value),
    second_transform(value)
  ]
}

get_list(12)
```

I guess this is the inverse of the [map](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#map) function.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You've got a few options for this.

Assuming your functions are already in a list:

```
transforms = [first_transform, second_transform];
```

The first option is to use [`R.juxt`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#juxt), which does pretty much exactly what you're after by creating a new function that applies the list of given functions to the values received by the new function.

```
get_list = R.juxt(transforms);
```

Another option is [`R.ap`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#ap), which applies a list of functions to a list of values. [`R.of`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#of) can be used to wrap the value in an array.

```
get_list = R.compose(R.ap(transforms), R.of);
```

Or lastly, [`R.map`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#map) could be used to receive each function in the list and return the result of applying it to the value.

```
get_list = value => R.map(fn => fn(value), transforms);
```

Comment: Doesn't R.map return array, instead of one value?

Comment: @RafałŁużyński `R.map` does indeed return an array if you are mapping over an array, like in this example. It can also return others if you are mapping over other supported types such as functions and objects. Refer to https://ramdajs.com/docs/#map for more detail.